# How to convert TimeZoneInformation into TimeZoneInfo

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I need get [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object that represent timezone on SharePoint Server. In client object model I found object Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone (Class [TimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.timezoneinformation_members%28v=office.15%29.aspx)).

How I can convert instance of TimeZoneInformation to TimeZoneInfo?